# Strange error: ImportError: No module named PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, importerror

When I run Python, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PIL
```

I don't understand what the problem could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PIL is deprecated, you must now use pillow.

Run the command:

```
pip install Pillow
```